# Azure HTTP function trigger 2.x with Cosmos DB Output local dev host failing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I am developing a http trigger using azure functions 2.x and dotnet core, after the latest update to VS 2017 15.8.2 I am getting the following error when running the function locally

```
1/9/2018 13:30:50] Stopping Host
[1/9/2018 13:31:06] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Users\MattDouhan\source\repos\NWMposTransInput\NWMposTransInput\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\host.json'
[1/9/2018 13:31:06] Host configuration file read:
[1/9/2018 13:31:06] {}
[1/9/2018 13:31:06] Starting Host (HostId=desktop7cks1do-260439321, InstanceId=5fd41a43-b3ca-47e4-adf6-320d40fa9613, Version=2.0.11960.0, ProcessId=13156, AppDomainId=1, Debug=False, ConsecutiveErrors=5, StartupCount=6, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[1/9/2018 13:31:07] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[1/9/2018 13:31:07] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IWebJobsStartup' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[1/9/2018 13:31:07] Stopping Host
```

I am running Function Core tools 2.0.1-Beta.35 and runtime version 2.0.11960.0

The function looks as follows

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace NWMposTransInput
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req, ILogger log,
            [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "xxxx",
            collectionName: "yyyy",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnection")]out dynamic document,
            ILogger log2)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            document = new { SSourceSystem = "jongelSystem",
                             id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                             SSourceSystemVersion = "1.1",
                             STransactionId = "12345"};

            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function inserted one row");
            log.LogInformation($"Description={req.Body}");

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
    }

    public class NWCloudOrder
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string SSourceSystem { get; set; }
        public string SSourceSystemVersion { get; set; }
        public string STransactionId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

--- EDIT ---
Making sure I use the correct runtime this now produces the following error

```
[2/9/2018 05:44:15] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[2/9/2018 05:44:15] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
[2/9/2018 05:44:15] Stopping Host
```

I do have 2.2.0-preview1-35029 installed

Comment: Please edit your question to include details for your Azure Function. With no code, and just a few error log statements, it's difficult to guess what could be happening. Also, you tagged this as `azure-cosmosdb` - is this relevant? Please clarify when you edit.

Comment: clarified as requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caused by referencing `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` of latest version  `3.0.1-beta1/2` in old function runtime `2.0.11960.0`. `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.19` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB 3.0.1-beta2` depends on runtime `2.0.12050.0`.

Check this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3363#issue-355824167) with relevant error info for breaking changes of latest runtime `2.0.12050.0`.

If you don't want to move to latest runtime for now, downgrade `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` to `3.0.0-beta7` and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.14`.

Else just make sure VS consumes the latest function runtime `2.0.12050.0`.

1. On VS menus-> Extensions and Updates. Find Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools. Make sure it's >= 15.8.5023.(Need to update VS to 15.8 first).
2. Delete old Function Core tools(Cli) folder `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools`.
3. Restart VS and create a new Azure function. Wait at the creation dialog for VS to download new Cli and templates, until we see the tip change to Updates are ready.

   [image]

   [image]

**Update**

1. Check Cli output, I am afraid older version 2.0.11651.0 is in use.

   ```
   Starting Host (HostId=xxx, InstanceId=xxx, Version=2.0.11651.0, ...)
   ```

   Go to `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases`, you may also see an empty folder `2.5.1`.

   The download failed due to some reason like network. Repeat the steps above again. If it doesn't work, try to download Cli manually. Close VS first.

   1). Open `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools\feed.json` to find latest download url of v2.

   e.g. cli: https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/2.0.1-beta.36/Azure.Functions.Cli.win-x86.2.0.1-beta.36.zip.

   2). Rename unzipped folder as `cli`, put it under `2.5.1`.

   3). Move `templates` folder in `cli` folder to `2.5.1`.

   4). Create a manifest.json under `2.5.1`.(Change your UserName)

   ```
   {
    "ReleaseName": "2.5.1",
    "CliEntrypointPath": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\2.5.1\\cli\\func.exe",
    "TemplatesDirectory": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\2.5.1\\templates",
    "FunctionsExtensionVersion": "~2",
    "SdkPackageVersion": "1.0.19"
   }
   ```
2. Function SDK references `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.1.0` by design. Remove `2.2.0-preview1-35029` or we may get error when executing.

   ```
   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'req'. System.Private.CoreLib: Cannot create an abstract class.
   ```

Comment: This produces a separate error, I have edited my question to add the current issue

Comment: Works like a charm, one thing to note the templates cannot be downloaded in china without VpN that’s why my update failed

Comment: @MattDouhan Yeah, that's a constant pain, I failed to download it sometimes even with VPN. Could you accept my answer to close the question?