# Why does my Azure V2 time function crashes with newtonsoft reference?

Tags: azure, json.net, azure-functions

I have a simple timer based azure function that crashes with the following message

I have added the nuget package for newtonsoft.Json so I am not sure why this is a problem.

```
[1/11/2018 07:00:26] Executed 'PimDataFeeder' (Failed, Id=291e9147-7f57-4fd3-887d-a8001afc8230)
[1/11/2018 07:00:26] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: PimDataFeeder. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
```

---- EDIT ----

The simple function looks like this, basically it downloads a file from a remote destination and manipulates it in memory before writing it into a CosmosDB instance, or at least thats the idea once it starts working. Putting a break point in the loop tells me that the first loop iteration works and indeed the first line from the string is split properly and then follows the crash

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Handlers;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NWCloudPimDataFeeder
{
    public static class PimDataFeeder
    {
        [FunctionName("PimDataFeeder")]
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            // The endpoint to your cosmosdb instance
            var endpointUrl = "https://example.com";
            // The key to you cosmosdb
            var key = "XXX";
            // The name of the database
            var databaseName = "XXX";
            // The name of the collection of json documents
            var databaseCollection = "XXX";

            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer XXX");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage file = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com");
            var content = await file.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            MemoryStream originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(content);
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                MemoryStream decompressedFileStream = new MemoryStream();
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                byte[] fileResult = new byte[decompressedFileStream.Length];
                decompressedFileStream.Position = 0;
                decompressedFileStream.Read(fileResult, 0, fileResult.Length);
                string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileResult);
                //log.Info(result);

                foreach (var singleItem in result.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    log.Info("singleItem looks like: " +singleItem);
                    log.Info("In the loop");
                    var itemWrapper = new ItemWrapper { NWID = Guid.NewGuid(), Item = singleItem, DocumentType = "Item"};

                    // Create a cosmosdb client
                    using (var docClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), key))
                    {
                        // Save the document to cosmosdb
                        docClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, databaseCollection), itemWrapper)
                            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ItemWrapper
    {
        public Guid NWID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [JsonProperty("item")]
        public string Item { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [JsonProperty("documentType")]
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, the packages you need for Azure Functions depend on a specific Newtonsoft.Json version. There's probably something wrong with the versions. Don't you get any build warnings or messages?

Comment: no build warnings no, just runtime, I tried to look for required versions but so far didn't find any, still looking

Comment: it requires 11.0.2 which is what I have

Comment: R u using VS 2017?

Comment: Yes VS 2017 15.8.8

Comment: @MattDouhan Could you share your code? The timer trigger template doesn't cause error on my side.

Comment: Added the Function

Comment: Can you please check which different versions of the library are used by you on one side and your dependencies on the other side (just traverse through or check the nuget specs) afterwards check your output folder and the binding redirects that they match the correct version.

Comment: Well you can see from the error message it’s looking for 11.0.0.0 which is not what I have I have installed 11.0.2 which is what the sdk needs if you try install another version you get compiler warnings about dependence errors so not sure what is looking for 11.0.0.0.0

Comment: @MattDouhan what version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions nuget package have you installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the Cli and Runtime is output as below when we debug function in VS. And the function project is created with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.23(>=1.0.14) references Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 by default.

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.1.748 Commit hash: 5db20665cf0c11bedaffc96d81c9baef7456acb3)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12134.0
```

I can only repro the problem with some old Function runtime, which still requires v10 Newtonsoft.Json. So check Function runtime version and make sure VS consumes the latest.

**Download and set cli manually**

1. Delete old Function CLI using by VS. Remove subfolders under `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases`.
2. Delete template engine consumed by VS `%userprofile%\.templateengine`.
3. Go to CLI feed to download latest cli, right now it's [feed 2.10.1 and CLI 2.1.748](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/blob/master/cli-feed-v3.json#L370).
4. Go to `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases` and create folder `2.10.1`.
5. Decompress the zip and rename it to `cli`, drag it under  `2.10.1`.
6. Copy `templates` folder under `cli` to `2.10.1`, and rename two files inside by removing version. e.g `itemTemplates.2.0.0-10300.nupkg` to `itemTemplates.nupkg`.
7. Create a manifest.json under `2.10.1` as below and change username.

   ```
       {
         "CliEntrypointPath": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\2.10.1\\cli\\func.exe",
         "FunctionsExtensionVersion": "~2",
         "MinimumRuntimeVersion": "2.1",
         "ReleaseName": "2.10.1",
         "RequiredRuntime": ".NET Core",
         "SdkPackageVersion": "1.0.23",
         "TemplatesDirectory": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\2.10.1\\templates"
       }
   ```

The folder structure should be like this

[image]

After restarting VS, everything should work as expected.

Comment: How do I ensure that ?

Comment: Hi @MattDouhan, so you did see old version on your side? Can you recall this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128635/azure-http-function-trigger-2-x-with-cosmos-db-output-local-dev-host-failing)? You once found the runtime is old 2.0.11651.0.

Comment: I read many threads about this on SO and it seems my cli tools might be at fault, whatever I do only get beta 25 nothing newer and others posts say that’s to old but whatever I do I cannot get newer

Comment: @MattDouhan You once said with VPN connected your VS downloads new cli successfully. This time you can't download any more even with VPN fine?

Comment: Whatever I do with or without vpn only beta 25 gets downloaded I get a folder for beta 26 but it’s always empty and nothing newer

Comment: @MattDouhan Have you managed to work with latest cli using manual steps above?

Comment: [3/11/2018 10:50:42] System.Net.Http: The operation was canceled. System.Net.Sockets: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Comment: your worker runtime is not set. As of 2.0.1-beta.26 a worker runtime setting is required.
Please run `func settings add FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME <option>` or add FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME to your local.settings.json
Available options: dotnet, node, python

Comment: @MattDouhan Try to create a new Timer Trigger template and copy your code.

Comment: 20 lines of code and 4 days debugging the tool chain :) but now it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

These errors are often times caused by not having the latest version of the Functions SDK/Tools installed. The reference to Newtonsoft 11.0.0 suggests that this might be the be the case (latest version is 11.0.2). You can navigate to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates (bottom left of window) in VS to check for updates to Azure Functions tooling. Once you have the latest update, trying re-creating the function to see if it works.